# convert JSON to contentvalues

Tags: android, sqlite, reflection, xamarin.android

Is there an easy way to get JSON from a webservice and put it into my SQLite DB in C# mono for android (xamarin)?
There are some tedious ways to do it but I want something quick and elegant.

Comment: Do you know what the JSON will look like, or do you need to handle arbitrary JSON? SQL databases require that you know about the columns you are about to store before you store things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a static class that will convert any object into contentvalues using reflection.  I'm sure there's an equivalent way to do this in Java.
Put your JSON objects into a class of some sort and this will convert all of the properties into contentvalues.

```
public static class Util
{
    //suck all of the data out of a class and put it into a ContentValues object for use in SQLite Database stuff
    public static ContentValues ReflectToContentValues(object o)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        foreach (var props in o.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            object val = props.GetValue(o, null);
            //check if compatible with contentvalues (sbyte and byte[] are also compatible, but will you ever use them in an SQLite database?
            if (props.CanRead && props.CanWrite && (val is double || val is int || val is string || val is bool || val is long || val is float || val is short))
            {
                cv.Put(props.Name, val.ToString());
                Log.Info("CVLOOP", props.Name + ":" + val.ToString());
            }
            else if (val is DateTime)
                cv.Put(props.Name, ((DateTime)val).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        }

        return cv;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The question is old, but here is the equivalent code of @gghuffer in Java:

```
public static ContentValues objectToContentValues(Object o) throws IllegalAccessException {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    for (Field field : o.getClass().getFields()) {
        Object value = field.get(o);
        //check if compatible with contentvalues
        if (value instanceof Double || value instanceof Integer || value instanceof R.string || value instanceof Boolean
                || value instanceof Long || value instanceof Float || value instanceof Short) {
            cv.put(field.getName(), value.toString());
            Log.d("CVLOOP", field.getName() + ":" + value.toString());
        } else if (value instanceof Date) {
            cv.put(field.getName(), new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format((Date)value));
        }
    }

    return cv;
}
```

For use this, you need to use the library of `Gson` and define java classes for all your `json` (i.e. 1 object - 1 json), then, for every class, you need to implement the following piece of code:

```
 public static YourClass fromJSON(String dpJSON) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(dpJSON, YourClass.class);
 }
```

Finally, you have your json string `jsonStr`, so:

```
ContentValues cv = Util.objectToContentValues(YourClass.fromJSON(jsonStr));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I made the following class to handle this when using `@SerializedName` annotations, it also adds support for ignoring certain fields. Hope it helps someone.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class ContentValuesWriter {

    public static ContentValues objectToContentValues(Object o, Field... ignoredFields) {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            //Will ignore any of the fields you pass in here
            List<Field> fieldsToIgnore = Arrays.asList(ignoredFields);

            for(Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);

                if(fieldsToIgnore.contains(field))
                    continue;

                Object value = field.get(object);
                if(value != null) {
                    //This part just makes sure the content values can handle the field
                    if(value instanceof Double || value instanceof Integer || value instanceof String || value instanceof Boolean
                            || value instanceof Long || value instanceof Float || value instanceof Short) {
                        values.put(field.getAnnotation(SerializedName.class).value(), value.toString());
                    }
                    else if (value instanceof Date)
                        values.put(field.getName(), Constants.DATE_FORMAT_FULL.format((Date) value));
                    else
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("value could not be handled by field: " + value.toString());
                }
                else
                    Print.log("value is null, so we don't include it");
            }

            return values;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Print.exception(e);
            throw new NullPointerException("content values failed to build");
        }
    }

}
```

You'll need to replace a few things there which are custom to my app, just the date format and Print function.